# How can I limit the number of results in PowerView chart

Tags: performancepoint, powerview

I can't figure this out and maybe its not possible with this tool. Maybe something like Performance Point is better for this (I've never used PP, just from what I read)

What I'm looking to is to shop sales by firm in a bar chart but limit the result to the top 5 selling. I've got the chart working, but it just shows the full result set. I definitely don't think its an option in the chart. By the way, I want to be able to allow user to drill down on a firm and have the agent sales underneath, again top 5.

I have drill down working correctly except for top issue again.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/filtering-results-to-only-show-top-x-results-in-power-view-chart/

Does this help?

"create a DAX measure that determines the Rank of each postalcode by sum of data:
=RANKX(ALL(CityData[PostalCode]),[Sum of Data])"

"Now I put that measure in the map filter area and start filtering on it. This gives us only the top 2 ranked cities:"

Comment: Thanks John, that's exactly what I was looking forward. Appreciate it